# GPU Driver Problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, gpu

I installed wubi 12.04 LTS. After restart, ubuntu says its starting for the firts time and gives an error: "stopping system v runlevel compatibility[OK]". Then monitor starts to go black and come back every second.

My gpu:

```
SiS 651_661FX_741_760_760GX_M661FX_M661MX_M741_M760_M760GX
```

After searching for a bit I found that I have to install the driver manually. Driver is here: "http://w3.sis.com/support/support_faqs_16.htm" and I dont know what to do with it. I am using windows xp sp3.

The reason I installed wubi at the beginning was to see if my wireless adapter (tl-wn721n) works. I may not have internet connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a link that says you have to install the driver manually.

Comment: @mikewhatever I dont remember where did I find but 15 to 20 minutes ago I restarted ubuntu with failsafe graphics (or something like that) and it said I have to do it manually.

Comment: you'll have a much, much easier time if you just pick up a 10 year old GeForce for $20 somewhere -- SiS graphics weren't very good in the first place, and they'll make your Linux experience more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @serilain Agreed! A 10 year old might be a little extreme, but something like a second hand Geforce 7600 would be a good choice.

Comment: fair enough -- a 7600 would in fact be a good choice as it's the oldest mainstream card with shader model 3, and I hate to give the impression that all linux users are junk merchants, but the fact is that a 10 year old card would still be better than the SiS chipset!

Comment: and, for that matter, I hate having to tell people to get different hardware in order to use linux -- thankfully it's not nearly as much of a problem as it used to be. ancient junk is still ancient junk, though.